# Autotabbing is adding far too much space in error. Can't seem to turn it off

Tags: visual-studio, razor

Visual Studio will automatically indent HTML on a cshtml file when C# is added below.

EG

```
@{
    <partial>...
    <div>....
        <button>...
}
```

Will auto-tab to the below if code is added and auto completes such as a simple open closing bracket as shown

```
@{
        <partial>...
        <div>....
            <button>...
} {}
```

Does anyone know how to turn off the autotabbing feature as nothing seems to be working.

Tried setting the All Languages > Tabs > Indenting to None, same for all other code bases.
Tried turning off Text Editor > Advanced > Use adaptive formatting